# Linearly independent algebraic integers form an integral basis

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n$ be a set of linearly independent algebraic integers such that $$\Delta_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n)=d$$

where $d$ is the discriminant of $K$. How do I show that the $\alpha$'s actually form an integral basis for $K$?

I tried a lot but I couldn't come up with anything substantial. First thing I tried was to extend this linearly independen set to a basis, but that didn't lead anywhere.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You know that some integral basis does exist; call it $\{\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n\}$. You can write down the coordinate vector of each of your $\alpha_i$'s with respect to this basis, and make them the columns of a matrix. It's invertible because of linear independence. Since the discriminants match, and their ratio is the determinant (or square of the determinant?) of that change-of-basis matrix, then we know that it is invertible in integers. That makes your set an integral basis, I think.

Does that work?

Comment: I don't think so, because a linearly independent set will have cardinality less than or equal to $n$. Which means that the change of basis matrix won't be square.

Comment: Isn't $\Delta_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ only defined when the set is a basis of the field? It's a determinant, too, so there have to be enough $\alpha_i$'s to make a square matrix there. That should give you the right cardinality, and all you have to show is that the given field basis is also an integral basis. Or, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There is a general fact:

Let $\Lambda\subseteq\Lambda'$ be lattices in the number field $K$. Then,

$$\text{disc}(\Lambda')=\text{disc}(\Lambda)[\Lambda:\Lambda']^2$$

This is just a standard trick using Smith normal form. Then, from this, you see that if $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m\in\mathcal{O}_K$ with $\text{disc}(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m)=d_K$ then the above formula implies that

$$\left[\mathcal{O}_K:\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}\alpha_i\right]^2=1$$